# Mysql query, check two users born at same date

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query to extract two users who who live on same adress from a table, in which I have these fields(id, username, date_of_birth, address)

Comment: The date doesnt play any important role in whole query, address does

Comment: Group by address having count(*) > 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment helped, here's the same in an answer :)

```
SELECT u.* FROM (
    SELECT address
    FROM users
    GROUP BY address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) addresses
INNER JOIN users AS u USING (address);
```

Or, if you want address with comma separated user names:

```
SELECT address, GROUP_CONCAT(username)
FROM users
GROUP BY address
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get address duplicates

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` AS t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `Table` AS t2 WHERE t1.address = t2.address AND t1.id != t2.id)
```